# Pandas Time Series date range slicing based on a value in a column

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, stock

I have created a pandas df where I bring stock data from yahoo. I added a **Percentage Change** column and filter the df where **Percentage Change** > 0.02. No issues here. 
Now I want to add an additional selection parameter that would output a df where I can view the dates where the previous condition is True (pct_change > 0.02) **and** view 10 days prior and 10 days after the date that evaluates the condition  (pct_change > 0.02) to True.
I can't really get my head around how to even start. Any help would be appreciated. My code so far:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 27)
gspc2 = web.DataReader("^GSPC", 'yahoo', start, end)
gspc2.rename(columns={'Adj Close' :'Adj_Close'}, inplace=True) gspc2['pct_change'] = gspc2['Adj_Close'].pct_change()
gspc2 = gspc2.ix[(gspc2['pct_change'] > 0.0200)]
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea is:

1. Get the row indexes that meet your criterian
2. Expand the row indexes based on your range
3. Filter out duplicates

Here is an example, hope it helps

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = { 'a' : range(10, 24) }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['b'] = (df.a % 5 == 0) # marks row 0, and 5

# number to look back and forward
n = 1

# find the rows meet cretiria, row 0 and 5
rows = np.where(df.b)[0]

# expand
rows = [x for row in rows for x in range(row-n, row+n+1) if x>= 0]

# filter
rows = list(set(rows))

print df.loc[rows]
```

The output is:

```
     a      b
0   10   True
1   11  False
4   14  False
5   15   True
6   16  False
9   19  False
10  20   True
11  21  False
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the idea, Xin Hunag, I haven't tested it yet, but it looks interesting. I'll let you know soon how it went. cheers

Comment: It works for normal indices, but fails for Time Series index. I adapted it a bit, but still get errors. rows = gspc2.index[gspc2['pct_change'] == 0.000000]

rows = [x for row in rows for x in range(row-pd.DateOffset(days=1), row+pd.DateOffset(days=1)) if x>= 0]
print(rows)

Answer (score 0):

I made it work with Xin Huang's code serving me as a base

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime
import itertools

# bringing stock data
start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 27)
gspc2 = web.DataReader("UNG", 'yahoo', start, end)
gspc2.rename(columns={'Adj Close' :'Adj_Close'}, inplace=True)
gspc2['pct_change'] = gspc2['Adj_Close'].pct_change()


# gspc2['std_dev2'] = gspc2['pct_change'].std()*2
# gspc2['pct_change_mean'] = gspc2['pct_change'].mean()

# setting filter condition
condition = -0.07
row_filter, gspc2['row_filter'] = gspc2.index[gspc2['pct_change'] <= condition ], (gspc2['pct_change'] <= condition)

# window of days before and after the selected date
n = 3

selected_rows = [(pd.date_range(i - pd.DateOffset(days=n), periods=n*2+1)) for i in row_filter]
selected_rows = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(selected_rows))

# cumulative return n-2 days later after the day on which condition occured, without counting return on the day itself
gspc2['cum_pct_change_ndays_after'] = gspc2.Adj_Close.shift(-(n-2))/gspc2.Adj_Close - 1
gspc2['n_days_avg_return'] = gspc2.cum_pct_change_ndays_after.mean()

final_df = gspc2.loc[selected_rows].dropna().drop_duplicates().sort_index(ascending=False)



#print(row_filter)
# removing nan due to mismatch in market days vs calendar days and removing duplicates 

print(final_df)
print(final_df[final_df.row_filter])
```